# Distributed computing in R

Tags: r, distributed-computing, distributed-r

I worked out an estimator, and I would like check its performance by doing simulation studies with R. I want to repeat the experiment for 500 times. Unfortunately, the computation involved in the estimator is sophisticated. Each replication will take 15 minutes on my desktop. I am looking for some distributed computation approaches with R. How should I start? I googled this topic. There are some many posts about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest starting with the `foreach` package. If you're using `mac` or `linux` the following is the simplest way to do parallel computing:

```
# First we register a parallel backend. This will work on mac and linux.
# Windows is more complicated, try the `snow` package.
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4) # substitute for number of cores you want to run on.

# now we can run things in parallel using foreach
foreach (i = 1:4) %dopar% {
  # What's in here will run on a separate core for each iteration.
}
```

You should read the vignette for `foreach` as it's quite different to `for` (especially nested loops) and it is also quite powerful for combining results at the end and returning them.

Answer (score 2):

First step with any R problem as broad as this should be checking the CRAN Task Views. Oh look:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Note that StackOverflow isn't really the place for asking broad questions that are best answered with 'read that documentation over there' or 'why don't you try using tool X?'